# How to not load a reference/collection in NHibernate unless it is eagerly preloaded?

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I would like to create a requirement to pre-load all required entities before displaying them, to minimize the amount of database calls that are caused by negligence. Is it possible to force NHibernate to test a collection before returning it?

I had in mind something like checking `NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized()` before returning the object, not sure how to implement it globally without manually doing it for every property though.

Note: I would not want to enable eager loading for the whole application, just introduce a slightly smarter lazy-loading.

Answer (score 0):

the consumer should specify which paths should be eagerly loaded and the DAL should use SetFetchMode/Fetch to eagerload the path. all the data is fetched then.

Answer to Comment: after having the loaded data either

- `session.Close()` throws away the session
- `session.Clear()` detaches all instances
- `session.Evict(obj)` detaches obj and associated entities

e.g.

```
foreach (var item in queryresults)
{
    session.Evict(item);
}
```

all unitialized proxies and collections will now throw LazyLoadExceptions

Comment: I'm not sure you understood me, let me give an example: if I query `book` and I eagerly fetch `pages` then I can see all pages via `book.pages`. However if I query `book`, and *not* fetch pages, then I want `book.pages` to throw an exception.